# What kind of tools I should use on linux to develop J2ME applications for nokia mobile phones?

Tags: linux, java-me

What are the best tools out there?

Comment: netbeans 6.7 with j2me plugin wasn't even able to build it's own example projects

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- [Eclipse MTJ](http://www.eclipse.org/dsdp/mtj/),
- [Antenna](http://antenna.sourceforge.net/) and of course
- [Sun's WTK](http://java.sun.com/products/sjwtoolkit/)

Comment: Your links all point to the same place!

Omry is one of the guys who maintains Antenna, which is an important bit of infrastructure.

Comment: seems like the best combination so far

Answer (score 0):

The Sun WTK is a pretty good place to start.  You can download my project, Hecl, and have a look at how it's done, and borrow what you want: it's open source, and developed on Linux.

http://github.com/davidw/hecl/